# switch between 2 tabbar controllers swift ios

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I ve got 2 TabBar Controllers
Tabbar Controller A
Tabbar Controller B

from A.tab3 I need to switch to B.tab1

everything I ve done so far makes B.tab1 open within A.tab1. what I need is to open B.tab1 outside the "A" tabbar controller

any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: Could you give more information about your views hierarchy? Do you need to have only A or B TabBar shown at a time? Or TabBar B inside TabBar A?

Comment: This sounds like an anti-pattern, but if you must do it, I believe your problem is in that the tab bar controller's children by nature are inside of it, not replacing it. You need to make a tempViewController that will transition to the new tabBarViewController, probably giving it a navigation controller of it's own.

Answer (score 2):

solved with this bit of code:

```
let tbb = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarB") as! UITabBarController
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tbb
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, even though it is kind of obvious, ha.

Comment: Does previous tabbar dismissed and free up the memory??